# Joomla Moderated FAQs extension

Tags: joomla

Does anyone know a Joomla Extension for **moderated FAQs**?

Something which can let the users ask a question. After that the admin would have the option to moderate the question and respond to it...

Please let me know.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your users have to register to ask a question, you can accomplish this by allowing user contributed articles. You can add a customized submission form using ChronoForms that submits an article to your FAQ category. User submitted articles should default to unpublished which will give you the opportunity to moderate and answer the questions before publishing.

Comment: After all, I had to create the component from scratch... ChronoForms didn't had what I need (especially when listing restuls).